# Compare if the output values are sorted or not using tree map and comparator

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class tlcs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://tlcs.ets.org/clientservices/profile/createAcct/createAcct.do");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("inst_state"));
        Select s = new Select(element);
        List <WebElement> elementcount = s.getOptions();
        System.out.println(elementcount.size());
        for(int i=0 ;i<elementcount.size();i++)
        {
            String value = elementcount.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(value);
                }
    }

}
```

In above code i want to check the output value is sorted or not, using comparator.Any suggestion

Comment: Numeric sort or string sort?

Comment: in ascending order, string sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JDK 8 you can use the following solution:

```
List<String> labels = elementcount.stream()
  .map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
SortedSet<String> sorted = new TreeSet<>(labels); 
assertThat(labels, contains(sorted));
```